# Comparison Test proof

Tags: calculus

prove the following by using Cauchy Criterion

Suppose $|a_n| \le b_n$ for all $n$. If $\sum b_n$ converges then $\sum a_n$ also converges.

could you please help me with that how can I prove it by using Cauchy Criterion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cauchy criterion for series is simply to show that the sequence of partial sums is a Cauchy sequence. Since $\sum b_n$ converges, it is Cauchy, and hence:

$$\forall \epsilon>0,\,\exists m\in\mathbb{N},\,\forall n\geq 0,\,|b_m+b_{m+1}+\dots+b_{m+n}|<\epsilon$$

We need to show that this also holds for $\sum a_n$. To that end, observe that it is implied by the hypotheses that $b_n\geq 0$, so that $|b_m+b_{m+1}+\dots+b_{m+n}| = b_m+b_{m+1}+\dots+b_{m+n}$. We thus have that
$$|a_m+a_{m+1}+\dots+a_{m+n}|\leq |a_m|+|a_{m+1}|+\dots+|a_{m+n}|\leq b_m+b_{m+1}+\dots+b_{m+n},$$

so that $\sum b_n$ satisfying the Cauchy criterion implies that $\sum a_n$ also satisfies it, and hence $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: You are welcome!